# Tridion error while Publishing a Component

Tags: publishing

When I publish a Component, I am getting the following error:

> JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error 'JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation("tcm:119-6186", GetTcmUriWebDavURI(GetValueOfResourceComponent("WebDavPath","solution_promo_box_component_template")))' had error 'RenderComponentPresentation: If a component is specified, a template must be specified also''

I tried searching but unable to find the solution

Comment: looks like, `GetTcmUriWebDavURI(GetValueOfResourceComponent("WebDavPath","solution_promo_box_component_template")` not returning template . check it

Comment: Sounds like `solution_promo_box_component_template` is a variable that should have been resolved to a URI before this. You might be missing a TBB _before_ the DWT.

Comment: When i am trying this  component template , then to same error is coming `JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error 'JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation("tcm:119-6186", GetTcmUriWebDavURI(GetValueOfResourceComponent("WebDavPath","solution_promo_box_component_template")))' had error 'RenderComponentPresentation: If a component is specified, a template must be specified also''`

Comment: `GetValueOfResourceComponent` where is this method written?

Comment: Hi Raj,  not knowing where exactly this `GetValueOfResourceComponent`  function is written, I have just started using Tridion new to it

Comment: Assuming this worked at some point or for certain content, you can find out what's wrong by comparing a working Component Presentation with a "broken" one in Template Builder. This can show you what's missing in the package (e.g. a resource Component or TBB). One "gotcha" might be running the template against content in the right context. That might happen when the Config comes from a Template Publication, but you try running the template against the Content Publication. If that's the case, run Template Builder against a Component in your Publishing Publication.

Answer (score 1):

The error message gives us a clue that it cannot find the template to render the Component with.

I would suggest to debug this function `GetValueOfResourceComponent("WebDavPath","solution_promo_box_component_template")`

My guess is that it is returning null.  Maybe the "WebDavPath" should be the WebDavURL of the actual Component?  I also assume the template 'solution_promo_box_component_template' is mapped somewhere in a config file.  The return result should be a component template that the RenderComponentPresentation method can be rendered with.